# How does a SectionIndexer affect Android fast scroll?

Tags: android, listview

Inside `ArrayAdapter` implementing `SectionIndexer` there is code that checks for list items that starts with the same first letter -- so it can be consolidated.

Like this:

```
    alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int size = objects.length; 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        // Log.d("ObjectLength", String.valueOf(objects.length));

        ItemObject it = objects[i];
        String name = it.name;
        String s = name.substring(0, 1);
        s = s.toUpperCase();

        if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s)) {
            alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
        }
    }

    Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
    ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
    Collections.sort(sectionList);
    sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

    // sectionList.toArray(sections);

    for (int i = 0; i < sectionList.size(); i++)
        sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);
```

My question, does consolidating this way effect FastScrolling?  Sometimes on ListViews using `SectionIndexer`, the Fast Scroll isn't always smooth but "choppy".  I can remove the `SectionIndexer` from the situation and Fast Scroll suddenly scrolls smoothly and proportionally.

ADDED CODE:

```
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
```

Comment: the code you posted is executed every time when `getSectionForPosition`/ `getPositionForSection` is called?

Comment: @zapl I just added those methods up top so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988886/fastscrollbar-go-out-of-screen-when-sectionindexer-implemented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SectionIndexer does indeed affect fast scrolling.

When using a SectionIndexer, you're saying that you want users to be able to precisely jump to those sections of your data set. If data in those sections is distributed unevenly, then the fast scroller will move proportional to its progress through the set of sections instead of proportional to its progress through each individual item in the data set.

This is intentional; it's done this way so that when a user is dragging the fast scroll thumb each section is given equal weight. Precisely targeting any section is as easy as targeting any other section, even if one section only has one item and the sections on either side of it have hundreds.

Comment: Thank your for your input.  One more question to clarify:  When I said it was "choppy", I should have made clear that the fast scroll "thumb scroller" symbol is not proportional to the height of the screen when you are scrolling regularly.  Sometimes it jumps to the bottom, other times, it scrolls off screen.  But if you grab the scroller manually it IS proportional.  On my app, I kept Fast Scroll, and removed SectionIndexer and it scrolled perfectly (either way).  Does what I am saying make sense?

Comment: It moving off-screen is not normal. :) Make sure that you're supplying all of the methods of the SectionIndexer interface - it needs to be able to map both ways, from section index to adapter position and also from adapter position to the section index for that item. **Edit** Just saw your added code; your `getSectionForPosition` method is reporting that every item belongs in the first section. It should instead report the index of the section that position belongs to.

Comment: What is the correct return statement for that method?  It actually was "1", then earlier I changed to "0" with no change. (Edit:  The docs say it returns "the section index. If the position is out of bounds, the section index must be clipped to fall within the size of the section array." - Do you know how that is implemented?)

Comment: If you have sections [A, B, C], and position X belongs to section B, then `getSectionForPosition(X)` should return 1, as index 1 corresponds to section B. If X belonged to section A it would return 0, and if it belonged to section C it would return 2.

Comment: Oh I see.  The position corresponds to the position of the specific characters in the array.  So it doesn't make sense to use 0,1,2 etc ... it should be a dynamic index variable then?

Comment: Correct, it should not return a constant. :) Its return value will depend on the position passed as an argument.

Comment: Okay, I just marked this correct because I am certain that you just solved my problem and I see the flaw of my logic here.  If you are done, I understand, you've helped a lot here! Otherwise, I am looking for what to return still. I see where the section is returned in getPositionForSection, but I don't see corresponding data for positions.

Comment: You'll want to hold a similar mapping from position to the section that data belongs to. Even a simple `int[]` will do here, keys as positions and values as the corresponding section index. You can populate it at the same time that you populate the rest of your section indexing data.

Comment: @KickingLettuce I am having same issue of section indexer. It would be great if you can provide section indexer methods code snippets.

Comment: @BipinVayalu  I apologize but I am no longer using a SectionIndexer so I do not have the code on hand.  This was the only time I had attempted it and it was along time ago.